Analytical solution to a second-order derivative of a composite function problem
it’s been 30 years since I attended a Math lecture and I have been struggling with this particular problem for a while.
Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.
Given  $$ {f} \left( x \right) ={a_1}{x^3} {+} {a_2}{x^2} {+}{a_3}{x} {+}{a_4} $$
where    $ {0 < x < 1},$ and composite function
$$ {k} \left( t \right) ={f} \left( {g} \left( {t} \right) \right). $$
Is there a function or set of functions $ x = {g} \left( t \right) $ such that
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}    {k} \left( t \right)  = constant $$
for arbitrary values of $ {a_1}, {a_2}, {a_3}, {a_4} $?
Using the chain rule I got as far as
$$ \bigg[ 3a_1 \left( g \left( t \right) \right) ^2 + 2a_2 g \left( t \right) + a_3 \bigg]   \frac{d^2}{dt^2}    {g} \left( t  \right)+\bigg[ 6a_1 g \left( t \right) + 2a_2 \bigg] \left( \frac{d}{dt} g \left( t \right) \right) ^2=constant $$
but am unable to find a $g \left( t \right)$ that works for arbitrary values of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$
I think that if $ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} k \left( t \right)  = constant $ then $ k \left( t \right) $ should be quadratic, but am not sure if this helps.

how about g(t) = constant?

That is a solution but then I think  $$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}    {k} \left( t \right)  = 0. $$ I was looking for a solution where the constant is non-zero.

@Abezhiko:  my answer proved the 2 sentences of you comment, 11 hours before it.

A function $g$ works for every $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ iff it works for $a=(1,0,0,0)$, $a=(0,1,0,0)$, and $a=(0,0,1,0)$ (as it always works for $a=(0,0,0,1)$).
It works for $a=(0,0,1,0)$ iff $g''$ is constant i.e.
$$g(t)=\alpha t^2+\beta t+\gamma.$$
Such a $g$ also works for $a=(0,1,0,0)$ iff $gg''+(g')^2=constant$ i.e.
$(\alpha t^2+\beta t+\gamma)2\alpha+(2\alpha t+\beta)^2=constant$ i.e. $\alpha=0$.
$g(t)=\beta t+\gamma$ also works for $a=(1,0,0,0)$ iff $g(g')^2=constant$ i.e. $(\beta t+\gamma)\beta^2=constant$ i.e. $\beta=0$.
The only solution is therefore
$$g(t)=constant.$$

Thank you for the nice proof that there is no general solution apart from $g \left( t \right) = constant $. I will look into solutions for more specific sets of $ a_1, a_2, a_3,a_4$
